# How to locate an element in Ranorex when its attribute is not recognised?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, ranorex

I have been working a test automation project using Ranorex; an element was automatically identified with one of its attribute but it does not work.

From its HTML code, this element can be uniquely identified by using its `aria-label` attribute, but `aria-label` attribute is not listed in Ranorex spy, can I please ask how I can solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when Ranorex does not recognise an attribute or list it in Ranorex spy, you can still use this attribute to identify your element.

As shown below, say, the element you want to identify is high lighted in blue, click on **Edit in Spy**.

[image]

You should get a Element Browser window pops out, edit this element's expression to look for your `aria-label` attribute.

```
//element_tag[@aria-label = 'a_value']
```